# Multiple Domains and Subdomains Using Multisite Installation

Tags: multisite, database, installation, customization

I have the following domains/subdomains. They are all related to each other, yet they must be on different domains/subdomains

```
example.com

www.example.com (redirects to example.com)

sub1.example.com

sub2.example.com

example.net

www.example.net (redirects to example.net)

sub1.example.net

sub2.example.net
```

I would like to have a single WordPress installation for all the above (i.e., end up with a single DB). I do understand that I can setup a multisite installation if I have a single domain with subdomains. But for the above, this would mean I end up with TWO multisite installations (one for `example.com`, and another for `example.net`).

Is it possible to setup a single multisite installation with a single database allowing more than one main domain as shown above? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, I use 25 sub sites with different domains.

1- Point your domains to WP root folder.

2- Add a new site:

[image: add mu site]

3- Edit it:

[image: edit mu site]

4- Change URL to a new domain:

[image: edit site url]

Comment: Thanks. But can you please just explain a little more? I really need your help :)

Comment: are you can point domains for custom folders on your server?

Comment: I am using AWS, and pointing my domain `example.com` to the EC2 instance that has WP installed on it. I am doing the same for the subdomains. I also have setup WP to be multisite, with each subdomain setup in the network section of WP.

Comment: setup one subdomain multisite on your main domain *example.com*, add new site from site network, set it to `any.example.com`, then edit this site, click setting, manually change this sub url to `example.net`.

Comment: Ooooh, I see. I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you absolutely can. First you will want to enable multisite in your wp-config.php. Choose one site as the primary domain. After, you should be able to login and see "Network Admin" on the top left area. Look for "Sites" and select add site. You should be able to type in your permalink or domain here. You of course can also set up sub domains as well. Once this is done, you need to point your domains to the ROOT path of the wordpress install. I recommend looking into Domain mapping as well.